# ClassCastException id3 lib

Tags: java, id3lib

I have an error using id3 lib :

```
music = new MP3File(currentFile);
if (music.hasID3v2Tag()){
    ID3v2_2 tags = (ID3v2_2) music.getID3v2Tag();

    String artiste = artistTF.getText();
    if (artiste == null || artiste.isEmpty())
        artiste = "";
    tags.setLeadArtist(artiste);

    String titre = titleTF.getText();
    if (titre == null || artiste.isEmpty())
        titre = "";
    tags.setSongTitle(titre);

    music.setID3v2Tag(tags);
    music.save();
}
```

and getting this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_3Frame cannot be cast to org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_4Frame

Comment: First, flease share the stacktrace! Second, what are the references to *Frame instances - it is not possible to identify those.